# the Seattle area vs. the western Anbar province

Tags: definite-article

In the following sentences, is it okay to keep "the"?

> She was also forced to make an unscheduled landing in Redding, California, due to poor visibility as a result of the wildfires in **the** Seattle area.

> Rockets struck an Iraqi military base hosting U.S. troops in **the** western Anbar province and the capital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must keep *the* in *the Seattle area*.
It should be removed in *western Anbar province*, unless there is another Anbar province.

You could also say *western Washington state*.

*The Seattle area* is *the area* around Seattle.

Comment: Is there a rule for when to use the definite article in front of place words?

Comment: I don't know of a single rule. Note the difference between *the Seattle area*  and *Anbar Province* (Al Anbar Province, per Wikipedia). The head noun of the former is *area*, not a proper noun, while the latter is a proper noun as a whole. So, *the Seattle area* is the correct noun phrase, but *Seattle area* as an adjective may or may not be preceded by a definite article, depending on the situation.

Comment: How about expressions involving "district"? Does it involve a definite article? For example, should I say "the Lewark District" or "Lewark District"?

Comment: Some of this just depends on custom, which may be variable, e.g., The Ukraine, Ukraine. I don't know Lewark, so I can't answer that.

Comment: "Lewark" is just a made-up name. I only want to know whether expressions involving "district" take "the," and whether they behave like "area" or "province."